# Subtle difference in chkconfig entry

Tags: chkconfig

I'm not able to try this out on one of our machines, so I'm asking here instead!

Why does the following chkconfig entry in an init script work:

```
# chkconfig: - 95 05
```

whereas the following doesn't:

```
# chkconfig : - 85 15
```

Is it the fact that there is a space between the `chkconfig` and the `:`, or are the numbers important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the space that's doing it. From `leveldb.c`:

```
if (!strncmp(start, "chkconfig:", 10)) {
```

The numbers only determine when the initscript runs during startup and shutdown.